# How to avoid chrome disabling my dev extension installed outside the chrome store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developed an extension for my team with more than a dozen persons. And we used it internally. But some Windows-base-on colleagues now face a problem. When they update chrome to verson 37 and above, my extension is blocked by chrome, due to its not installing by chrome app store. Is there a cheap way to avoid this?

I had tried some methods. We don't want to change chrome into chromium or change their Windows into MacOS, Linux. And we want to update Automatically, so packaging on local is standby. Publishing in chrome app store is also a standby. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative deployment is available only if your computers are in a Windows domain. You can then use [this documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453) to set up distribution via Group Policy.

Other than that, no, you have to publish on the Web Store. It's $5, once, it's not that costly. You can set your item to be Unlisted, so that it's not possible to install it without knowing an explicit link, or you can even restrict it to an explicit list of Google accounts.

As a bonus, if you [deploy to Web Store providing your packaging key](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/qZ5PXH2KzPs), I think the extension will be turned back on automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I had found a good way using Windows Registry to avoid it.